# R: Find where one variables contains the value of another

Tags: r

Working in R.  I want to look at one variable to see if it contains the contents of another.  This needs to be done element by element.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
         FirstName = c("Jon", "Rob", "Phil", "Andy"),
         BusName = c("Jon's Auto", "123 Taxis", "Plumber Phil", "Handy 
Plumbers")
```

I have tried lots of variations of grep/grepl/match/%in%/sub but this seems to only match a static string against the variable.  eg

```
grep("Jon",df1$BusName) would give me TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE but 
grep(df1$FirstName, df1$BusNAme) gives an error
```

I want to scan down and compare them element by element so the output would be TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE

Comment: `grep` is not vectorized for pattern, also, you need to convert it to `character` class

Answer (score 4):

We can convert the pattern column to `character`.  Note that `grep` is not vectorized for `pattern`.  Using `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(df1$BusName, as.character(df1$FirstName))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: When i ran it i got the following error:  Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : object 'C_stri_detect_regex' not found

Comment: @J.Homer  Not able to reproduce the error with the example you showed.  Are you getting the error with the same data.  What is the version of `stringr`?  I am using `packageVersion("stringr")#
[1] ‘1.3.1’`

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `mapply` and `grepl` to "vectorize" over the arguments:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  FirstName = c("Jon", "Rob", "Phil", "Andy"),
  BusName = c("Jon's Auto", "123 Taxis", "Plumber Phil", "Handy Plumbers"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df1$match <- mapply(grepl, df1$FirstName, df1$BusName)
print(df1$match)
#  Jon   Rob  Phil  Andy 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider accepting an answer to your question (this or akrun's answer) if either indeed answered your question